# SweetAlert button not clicking properly - Angular/Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm running some tests for CRUD functionality on an Angular app I'm working on. The basic idea behind it is that there are 3 buttons. Create, Edit, and Delete. Keep in mind all this functionality works in the UI. The create and edit buttons open a modal and submit information. Once that information is submitted, a SweetAlert pops up that tells the user it was successful, and the test clicks the OK button. It works fine for these 2.

However, there is an issue with the Delete button. When it gets clicked, it gets to a screen where you can choose between the (.cancel) button and the (.confirm) button. It's finding the buttons but not executing the .click() for whatever reason. So I'm able to create/edit the content but not delete it, because this button won't click. Any idea why?

Here's a pic of the alert:
http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/sweetalert_zps7na0nsua.png

Below is the tests for this specific page:

```
describe('Main CRUD Banners Page', function() {

  var create_edit = element.all(by.model('vm.create'));
  var remove = element.all(by.css('button[ng-  click="vm.deleteMainBanner(banner)"]'));
  var modal_title = element(by.css('.modal-header h3'));
  var name = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Name"]'));
  var author = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Author"]'));
  var title = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Title"]'));
  var date = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Date"]'));
  var submit = element(by.css('button[ng-click="vm.submit()"]'));
  var submit_confirmation = element(by.css('p[style="display: block;"]'));
  var button_confirmation = element(by.css('.confirm'));
  var new_banner_name = element.all(by.binding(' banner.name ')).last();
  var new_banner_author = element.all(by.binding(' banner.author ')).last();
  var delete_confirm = element(by.buttonText('Yes Delete'));

  function createContent(test_name, test_author, test_title, test_date) {
      name.sendKeys(test_name);
      author.sendKeys(test_author);
      title.sendKeys(test_title);
      date.sendKeys(test_date);
      submit.click();
  }

  beforeEach(function(){
      browser.get('http://localhost:3444/ind_page/content/mainbanner');
  });

  it('should be logged in on main banner page', function(){
      expect(element(by.binding(' app.username   ')).getText()).toContain('jonathan');
     expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('http://localhost:3444/ind_page/content/mainbanner');
  });

  it('should open a create modal and submit main banner content',   function(){
      create_edit.first().click();
      //expect(modal_title.getText()).toBe('Create Content');
      createContent('test_banner', 'jay', 'Get Fit, Make Money', '12/14/15');
      expect(submit_confirmation.getText()).toContain('Complete');
      button_confirmation.click();
      expect(new_banner_name.getText()).toBe('test_banner');
  });

  it('should open an edit modal and submit changes to main banner content', function(){
      create_edit.last().click();
      //expect(modal_title.getText()).toBe('test_banner');
      author.clear().sendKeys('test_author');
      submit.click();
      expect(submit_confirmation.getText()).toContain('Complete');
      button_confirmation.click();
      expect(new_banner_author.getText()).toBe('test_author');
  });

  it('should delete main banner content', function(){
      remove.last().click()
      expect(submit_confirmation.getText()).toContain('You will not be able to recover this record');
      delete_confirm.click();
      expect(submit_confirmation.getText()).toContain('The record has been deleted');
      button_confirmation.click();
  });

});
```

HTML -

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading banner-title">Main Banners Posted</div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:420px;overflow:auto">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th><a ng-click="vm.create=true;vm.fields[0].disabled=false;vm.mainBannerManagement()"
                        ng-model="vm.create">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="banner in vm.main_banners | orderBy: 'name'">
                <td>{{ banner.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ banner.thumbnail_picture_url }}</td>
                <td>{{ banner.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ banner.date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="vm.create=false;vm.fields[0].disabled=true;vm.mainBannerModelUpdate(banner);vm.mainBannerManagement()"
                            ng-model="vm.create"
                            type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button ng-click="vm.deleteMainBanner(banner)" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Alert function in JS file -

```
vm.deleteMainBanner = function(model) {
    SweetAlert.swal({
        title: 'Delete: Are you sure?',
        text: 'You will not be able to recover this record',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes Delete',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm){
        if(isConfirm === true){
            var u = new Generic('content', model.name);
            u.delete();
            SweetAlert.swal('Deleted!', 'The record has been deleted', 'success');
            console.log('hi im deleting shit');
            $state.reload();
        }
        else{
            SweetAlert.swal('Cancelled', 'Cancelled Deletion', 'error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How does it currently fail? Also, please post the HTML code of the delete confirmation "popup". Thanks.

Comment: Added the HTML/JS to my original post. The test isn't technically failing, at least on the test suite, but it's not correctly doing what it is supposed to. It's supposed to click the confirm button, which automatically removes that item from the list of content. (this is what happens when I do it manually in the UI). 

I put a console.log where the alert happens to see if it was even going off when protractor is running and it's not (it goes off when I do it manually).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your protractor is trying to click before the rendering of your alert is done. Could you show the error message?

You should try to give an id to your modal alert and wait this to be visible with an Expected Condition from protractor (example just below) or just wait the delete button to be clickable:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
// Do your stuff ... 
// Then wait button to be visible and enabled  
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(delete_confirm), 5000).then(function(){
    expect(submit_confirmation.getText()).toContain('You will not be able to recover this record');
    delete_confirm.click();
});
```

Keep in mind protractor is working asynchroneously, to be sure all your tests going to be stable, wait a condition after each new rendering. Else you can have troubles with loader or backdrops.

```
var myBackdrop = element(by.id(backdropId));
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(myBackdrop), 5000);
```

Take a look to this page, this can solve most of the random failures in e2e tests. https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

---

If the problem still here, use one of this tricks:

```
delete_confirm.click().click();
// or 
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", delete_confirm);
// or
browser.actions().mouseMove(delete_confirm).click().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll go ahead and give this a shot. There's no actual error message, so it's hard to figure out. I just know it's not working because when I go back to the index of content, that piece of content is still there in the list, but it should be gone.

Comment: Tried it out with the EC/wait stuff. It's still not working. The button is rendering and it's clickable. I chained another .wait onto the second alert screen, which is supposed to go off once you click the 'delete_confirm' button, to check for that button that says 'OK' with the message of 'The record has been deleted'. It's just straight up not executing it. I have no idea why.

Comment: Hmm strange behavior, you tried to change the propertie element(by.buttonText('Yes Delete')); by another like by.id or by.css ?? else try a browser.debugger() after clicking the delete button, launch protactor with your e2e debug propertie and open (F12) console to see if an error occured. a browser.sleep(60000); can work too if you are fast enough ^^

Comment: Did quite a bit of debugging. Still could not find anything. The weirdest thing is all the tests pass with 'Firefox', including the delete, and everything except the delete works in 'Chrome'. So it seems to be an issue with Chrome. Have no idea how to debug that since no errors come up.

Comment: Ok annoying problem ^^, so perhaps check the webdriver manager version and protractor version could help ... , what are the version of your selenium-server-standalone and chrome driver version ? Can you update them to newer respective version 2.48.2 and 2.20 ?